# react.js text div wont scale with my page but the image div will

Tags: css, reactjs

I am doing this website for my full stack web development course but I am having a bit of trouble with my css. I am wondering how I can get the text Div to scale with the page.

the div looks like this zoomed in,
[image: Div zoomed in]

and it looks like this zoomed out,

[image: image zoomed out]

the text div always wants to stay the same size.

the css is

```css
.waitingMainDiv {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.waitingLeftDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.waitingLeftDivImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.waitingRightDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.waitingTextDiv {
  width: 85%;
  color: grey;
}

.waitingTextDiv h2 {
  font-family: nunito;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  margin: 4%;
}

.waitingTextDiv h3 {
  font-family: nunito;
  margin: 30px;
}

.waitingTextDiv p {
  font-family: nunito;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.waitingButtonDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.waitingButtonDiv button {
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-family: nunito;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.waitingEnquireButton {
  border: 2px solid #43c0f6;
  background-color: white;
  color: #707070;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.waitingSignUpButton {
  border: 2px solid #f91c85;
  background-color: #f91c85;
  color: white;
}
```

and the react.js is

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js">
import teacherPicture from "../../../../img/teacherPicture.png";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Waiting.css";
import NavModal from "../../../Nav/NavModal";

export default function Waiting() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="waitingMainContainer">
      <div className="waitingMainDiv">
        <div className="waitingLeftDiv">
          <img className="waitingLeftDivImage" src={teacherPicture} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="waitingRightDiv">
          <div className="waitingTextDiv">
            <h2>What are you waiting for?</h2>
            <h3>Start teaching Digital Technologies today.</h3>
            <p>
              If you need more information, we are happy to answer any questions
              you may have.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="waitingButtonDiv">
            <button className="waitingEnquireButton">ENQUIRE NOW</button>
            <button
              onClick={() => handleOpen()}
              className="waitingSignUpButton"
            >
              SIGN UP
            </button>
            <NavModal open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
</script>
```

Thankyou to those who review my code, its definitely a simple fix but im driving myself crazy over it.

Answer (score 1):

Give your main div a width, not %;

```
.waitingMainDiv {
  width: 70vw; //changed
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but this didnt work, would i have to do the same to all?